# Trigger open event of KendoUI multiselect widget

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-mvc

I'm trying to cause the KendoUI multiselect dropdown to open automatically when a user tabs to this widget. I can trigger the open event via the console by doing

```
var widget = $("#MyWidget").data("kendoMultiSelect");
widget.focus();
widget.open();
```

I would like to do this automatically when the focus is on the KendoUI multiselect widget as a result of the user tabbing to it.

My setup: using the KendoUI MVC Wrapper for the Multiselect and IE9

I tried attaching a focus listener using the name I passed to the widget i.e.

```
$("#MyWidget").on('focus',function(e){
    alert("hi");
});
```

I was unable to detect a focus event this way. Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to trigger the open event of the KendoUI multiselect when the user tabs into the field! :) I added a keyup listener to the window object and was able to pick out the elements I was interested it. It's not very efficient but it works and I welcome improvements to it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on('keyup', function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 9) {
            //get element in focus
            var item_name = e.target.name;
            //get element in focus
            var focused_element = $(document.activeElement);
            //console.log(focused_element);
            var nextSib = focused_element[0].nextElementSibling;
            if (nextSib && nextSib.parentElement && nextSib.parentElement.nextElementSibling) {
                var select_element = nextSib.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
                //item_name will hold the name of the widget i.e. the value of the input field
                //.Name("myWidgetName")
                item_name = select_element.id;
                var obj_select = '#' + item_name;
                //true for multiselect widget
                if (select_element.type == 'select-multiple') {
                    var obj_selector = $(obj_select).data("kendoMultiSelect");
                    if (obj_selector) {
                        obj_selector.focus();
                        obj_selector.open();
                    }                    
                }else if (select_element.type == 'text'){
                    //true for combobox widget
                    var obj_selector = $(obj_select).data("kendoComboBox");
                    if (obj_selector){
                        obj_selector.open();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```